# GitLab CI/CD | How to Update a txt-File from a job within a pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd

I am trying to update a file in my repository via job within the pipeline.

my pipeline:

```
stages:
  - check_url

standardCheck:
  stage: check_url
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest 
  script:
    - pwsh -File ./variable.ps1
```

my script variable.ps1

```
#read status from file, initial "true"
$status = Get-Content -Path "status.txt"

# reads "true"
Write-Host "current Status: $status"

# set content to "false", doesn't work!
Set-Content -Path ".\status.txt" -Value "false" -Force

# right location
Write-Host $(Get-Location)

# reading the new status "false" works as well
Write-Host "Status after setting: $(Get-Content -Path "status.txt")"
```

my repo:

- gitlab-ci.yml
- status.txt
- variable.ps1

[image: my Repo]

I expected (that's my goal), the script would change the value of status.txt to "false". Not only within the job/pipeline. However I still have the value "true".

How can I update the file on easy way?
I tried to use ci global variable, however i could not override the value permanently. When the Pipelines starts, so it takes the default value and not the updated one.

My actually goal is, I need a status after executing job script, which can be accessed and overrode from same pipeline job at the next time. Depending on the status value, another processes are started.

1. Why does my above code not work?
2. Is there another way to achieve my goal to have a status of a value anytime in te gitlab instance?

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the `status.txt` file is stored in your Git repository. So if you want to change its state and be able to retrieve it next time, you should:

1. modify its content
2. git commit / push it to store its new content

But functionally it doesn't seem a good idea to use your Git repo to store your latest GitLab CI pipeline status. Moreover, committing it would trigger another pipeline, which might be an unexpected side effect (note: you could add `[skip ci]` somewhere in the commit message to prevent the pipeline from executing, but we're probably too far from your original question here)...

Maybe the best solution would be to use GitLab's APIs:

- [get latest pipeline's execution](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#list-project-pipelines) (use sort and [pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/rest/#pagination) to retrieve only the latest one)
- [get a pipeline's execution status](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html#get-a-single-pipeline)
- [get a job's execution status](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-a-single-job)